# Trane Weathertron Stat to Honeywell RTH2510

Tags: hvac, thermostat, heat-pump, heat

[image]I have a Trane Weathertron thermostat thst I am replacing with a New Honeywell RTH2510.
This is a heat pump with auxiliary electric heat.
The wires on the Tran thermostat are.
R,  T, O, G,  Y,  B,  X2  & W  (X2 & W are connected to same wire (jumper))

How do I connect wires on the RTH2510??
It has B, O, G, Y, W/AUX, NOT USED, R, RC
SEE ATTACHED PICTURES
[Trane stat[image: ][1]]

Comment: Can you post a wiring diagram for your heat pump?  Something's quite goofy with the O and B wires -- normally, you only have *one* wire from your 'stat to your heat pump's reversing valve.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Big points for photographing the original installation; most people disassemble everything and only then start wondering how to install the replacement.